# Python syntax error when using semicolons with `for`, `while` and `with` keywords in codegolf

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was playing some code golf and came across behavior I don't understand.

Why is the following code valid:

```
import os; print(1)
```

and this code is valid:

```
import os
for i in range(10): print(1)
```

but not:

```
import os; for i in range(10): print(1)
```

It errors out with:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
    import os; for i in range(10): print(1)
               ^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It breaks my mental model of how the semicolon works in python, shouldn't this be valid? If not, could someone explain why? Is there something special about the `for` and `while` keywords that prohibit oneliners?

What's a work around for playing code golf using python?

Comment: Note that Stack Overflow is limited to _practical_, answerable questions. We explicitly disallow codegolf -- kicked it out to [codegolf.se] Stack Exchange probably the better part of 15 years ago now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but there's no workaround for indentation in some cases. As a general rule when golfing you can't have a `;` and a `:` that introduces a new block (like `if`, `for`, `while`, `def`, `try` etc.) in the same line. Take it as one of the drawbacks of using Python as a golfing language.

That said, there can be other ways to get around it using some tricks which you acquire with practice. For example,

```py
import os
for i in range(10):
    print(1)
```

can be rewritten as

```py
import os;[print(1)for _ in' '*10]
```

(works as of py3.11)

Comment: What is the point of doing `for _ in' '*10` instead of `for i in range(10)`?!

Comment: @zvone Length. That's the point of code golf.

Comment: @zvone Using 14 characters vs using 18 characters. In golfing the shorter your code is, the better